# R dcast fill with a sample number

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2, dcast

I wonder if there is a way to `fill` with random numbers each individual missing value when using `dcast` (library `reshape2` or `data.table`). Example:

```
ID = c('AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD')
Replica = c('H1','H3','H1','H2','H1','H2','H3','H2','H3')
Value = c(1.3, 2.5, 1.4, 3.7, 9.5, 7.4, 7.1, 1.8, 8.4)

example <- data.frame(ID=ID, Replica = Replica, Value = Value)
```

Doing a simple `dcast`

```
dfdc <- dcast(data=example, ID~Replica, value.var = 'Value', fill = sample(1:10, 1))
```

notice how some of the values are missed:

```
  ID  H1  H2  H3
1 AA 1.3  NA 2.5
2 BB 1.4 3.7  NA
3 CC 9.5 7.4 7.1
4 DD  NA 1.8 8.4
```

I would like to fill up each of those missing values with random numbers, something like:

```
dfdc <- dcast(data=example, ID~Replica, value.var = 'Value', fill = sample(1:10, 1))
```

which gives as a result:

```
  ID  H1  H2  H3
1 AA 1.3 2.0 2.5
2 BB 1.4 3.7 2.0
3 CC 9.5 7.4 7.1
4 DD 2.0 1.8 8.4
```

However, all the missing values have been replaced by the same random number (2 in this case).

Would it be possible to apply the function individually to each missing value and, therefore, fill the missing values with different random numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you're not concerned with a warning, you could just do `fill = sample(10)`, and the unused values will be dropped.  You will still receive three random numbers.  Just make sure you're certain the sample is higher than the expected number of `NA` values.

```
dcast(example, ID ~ Replica, fill = sample(10))
#   ID   H1  H2  H3
# 1 AA  1.3 4.0 2.5
# 2 BB  1.4 3.7 1.0
# 3 CC  9.5 7.4 7.1
# 4 DD 10.0 1.8 8.4
# Warning message:
# In ordered[is.na(ordered)] <- fill :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Of course, you could simply wrap that with `suppressWarnings()` as well.

```
suppressWarnings(dcast(example, ID ~ Replica, fill = sample(10)))
#   ID  H1  H2  H3
# 1 AA 1.3 6.0 2.5
# 2 BB 1.4 3.7 5.0
# 3 CC 9.5 7.4 7.1
# 4 DD 9.0 1.8 8.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(example, ID, Replica) %>%
    mutate(Value = coalesce(Value, as.numeric(sample(1:10, n(), replace=TRUE))))  %>%       
    spread(Replica, Value)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
#      ID    H1    H2    H3
#* <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     AA   1.3   2.0   2.5
#2     BB   1.4   3.7   1.0
#3     CC   9.5   7.4   7.1
#4     DD   8.0   1.8   8.4
```